# Use windows authentication with ASP.Net AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax, authentication, active-directory

I'm working on my first application using ASP.Net with web services and I'm having an authentication issue. At least I think that's the issue.

When I run the application locally in debug mode it works fine. It even works when I run it out of debug mode (through IIS) in IE 7. But when I have a coworker run it (from my IIS) on their box, it doesn't work. When querying active directory to look up users it gives this error:

Sys.Net.WebServiceFailedException: The server method 'GetCurrentUser' failed with the following error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException - An operations error has occurred.

What do I need to do to get this working remotely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure IE is correctly identifying the zone as the Intranet so it will automatically send the username for it. If its not, you'll need to manually add the URL to the Intranet Zone in the IE settings.

That should resolve it, and depending on your config you may need to add to your web.config

What is your web.config for the webservice

Answer (score 0):

What is the authentication setting for the website in IIS?  Unless it is set to Integrated Windows authentication it is not likely a permissions issue.  If you want to rule out authentication, change the authentication method to Anonymous access and have your coworker try again.

Also, if you specify a user to impersonation in your web.config and you use a different user name in your active directory connection string it can cause an error but it is unclear if that is causing your issue.